# How do I convert eg '22/03/2005' to a datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Its SQL Server 2000.
I am starting with a character string in the format DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SELECT CAST('22/03/2005' AS datetime)

or 

SELECT convert(datetime,'22/03/2005', 103)
```

Comment: didn't know that set dateformat thing - handy not to have to remember opcodes

Answer (score 3):

Here's the table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Sample:

```
select convert(datetime,'22/03/2005', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends your the context.
SQL Server understands '2010-06-21' as a date without requiring any convert/cast, so I would just use the string in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' if that suits your needs.
Otherwise, the other responses using cast may be better if you need to compare with date fields containing hours as well.

Comment: You'd use yyyymmdd. 2010-06-21 is *not* safe if you have say british language settings